# Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 terminates every time

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop alongside Windows 7 as a dual boot PC. After selecting the option **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**, a black screen comes up showing the message `terminating all installation processes`. Then my PC reboots to Windows 7, and the installation terminates.

I have enough space on my hard disk (at least 30GB free on Disk C on which Windows 7 is installed). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow the instructions you find at the following link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot